# Is there a way to un-hybridize a MXNet network?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, mxnet

The MXNet deep learning framework offers `HybridBlock`s, which allow you to mix imperative programming (for debugging) and symbolic programming (for faster training). I have a network that I hybridized and ran, and would like to then "un-hybridize" the network to debug activation dimensions. But I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation that allows you to un-hybridize a compiled network. Is there anything in the MXNet framework that would allow me to accomplish what I'm attempting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`net.hybridize(active=False)` should do the trick. Looks like we didn't mention in the [hybridization tutorial](https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.6/api/python/docs/tutorials/packages/gluon/blocks/hybridize.html). I created [#18962](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/18962) for tracking this.